# create new matrix with new dimension and omitting NA values

Tags: r, matrix, dimension

I have a matrix with some NA values
for example:

```
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7    10
[2,]    2    NA   8    11
[3,]    3    6    NA   12
```

I want to create new matrix with data from my matrix above with new dimension and no NA value. (it is ok to have NA only some last elements)

something like:

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3] 
[1,]    1    6    11   
[2,]    2    7    12   
[3,]    3    8    NA   
[4,]    4    10   NA
```

I would appreciate if anyone can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward if you want to preserve order column-wise or row-wise.

```
originalMatrix <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,NA,6,7,8,NA,10,11,12),nrow=3)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2   NA    8   11
[3,]    3    6   NA   12

newMatrixNums <- originalMatrix[!is.na(originalMatrix)]

[1]  1  2  3  4  6  7  8 10 11 12
```

Pad with NA:

```
newMatrixNums2 <- c(newMatrixNums,rep(NA,2))
```

Column-wise:

```
matrix(newMatrixNums2,nrow=3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    8   12
[2,]    2    6   10   NA
[3,]    3    7   11   NA
```

Row-wise:

```
matrix(newMatrixNums2,nrow=3,byrow=T)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    6    7    8   10
[3,]   11   12   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this as well:

```
m <- matrix(1:12, nc=4)
m[c(5, 9)] <- NA

matrix(c(na.omit(c(m)), rep(NA, sum(is.na(m)))), nrow=4)
```

Comment: Ha, yeah I chose a bit of a complicated route to count the NAs!

Answer (score 2):

```
m <- matrix(1:12, nc=4)
m[c(5, 9)] <- NA


# create an array of the appropriate class and dimension (filled with NA values)
dims <- c(4, 3)
md <- array(m[0], dim=dims)
# replace first "n" values with non-NA values from m
nonNAm <- na.omit(c(m))
md[seq_along(nonNAm)] <- nonNAm
md
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    6   11
# [2,]    2    7   12
# [3,]    3    8   NA
# [4,]    4   10   NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another attempt. This will keep the order of the values in column order as a matrix usually would. E.g.:

```
mat <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,NA,6,7,8,NA,10,11,12),nrow=3)

array(mat[order(is.na(mat))],dim=dim(mat))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    4    8   12
#[2,]    2    6   10   NA
#[3,]    3    7   11   NA
```

Now change a value to check it doesn't affect the ordering.

```
mat[7] <- 20

array(mat[order(is.na(mat))],dim=dim(mat))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    4    8   12
#[2,]    2    6   10   NA
#[3,]    3   20   11   NA
```

You can then specify whatever dimensions you feel like to the `dim=` argument:

```
array(mat[order(is.na(mat))],dim=c(4,3))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    6   11
#[2,]    2   20   12
#[3,]    3    8   NA
#[4,]    4   10   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
# Reproducing your data
m <- matrix(1:12, nc=4)
m[c(5, 9)] <- NA

# Your desired dimensions
dims <- c(4, 3)
array(c(na.omit(c(m)), rep(NA, prod(dims) - length(na.omit(c(m))))), dim=dims)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    6   11
# [2,]    2    7   12
# [3,]    3    8   NA
# [4,]    4   10   NA
```

Comment: As @TylerRinker demonstrated, `rep(NA, prod(dims) - length(na.omit(c(m)))))` can be replaced with `rep(NA, sum(is.na(m)))`.

Answer (score 0):

This can do the job but dunno whether it is a good way.

```
list1 <- m[m]
list2 <- m[!is.na(m)]
element1 <- list2
element2 <- rep(NA, (length(list1)-length(list2)))
newm <- matrix(c(element1,element2), nrow=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you increase the length of a numeric vector with `length(x)<-` without assigning values to the new elements, the new values are given `NA` as their value. So `length(M2) <- length(M)` takes the shorter M2 vector and makes it the same length as M by adding `NA` values to the new elements.

```
## original
> (M <- matrix(c(1:4,NA,6:8,NA,10:12), nrow = 3))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    4    7   10
# [2,]    2   NA    8   11
# [3,]    3    6   NA   12

## new
> M2 <- M[!is.na(M)]; length(M2) <- length(M)
> matrix(M2, ncol(M))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    6   11
# [2,]    2    7   12
# [3,]    3    8   NA
# [4,]    4   10   NA
```